# Live audio stream using FFMPEG

Tags: usb, audio

I try to stream live audio using `ffmpeg` and external USB microphone. [I followed this nearly tutorial](http://prupert.co.uk/2010/08/02/stream-live-audio-from-a-microphone-in-near-real-time-in-ubuntu)

I had to adapt some steps but finally, I achieved to receive the stream my laptop using this command :

```
ffmpeg -f oss -i /dev/dsp1 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ac 1 -re -f rtp rtp://192.168.28.116:1234
```

The CPU is near 100%, i have a bad sound during two seconds and after nothing...
I see in Wireshark that the board is sending frames continuously.

Does someone have ideas to lower the CPU usage ?

Comment: You may want to look into overclocking and a different memory split. If you have the choice of codec you may be able to achieve some improvement by switching. You may also want to investigate compression of the stream - though this may be a zero some gain - anything you gain in transfer time may be lost in compression.

Comment: Did you try writing to a local file first? I'd try to go step by step: 1) realtime recording to a wave file, 2) realtime recording to an mp3 file 3) streaming stuff over the network

Comment: not at the moment. seems to be complicated to do all thoses steps manually instead of full automatic ffmpeg ;-)

Comment: What are you recording?

Comment: I'm trying to make an ethernet babyphone

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution?

Comment: I bought a Wolfson Audio Card for Raspberry Pi but i didn't had the time to try... The raspberry pi b/b+ was too slow without that. I suppose it will be better with the raspberry pi 2

Answer (score 8):

To answer your specific question, you can reduce CPU by piping arecord into ffmpeg:

```
arecord -f cd -D plughw:1,0 | ffmpeg -i - -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ac 1 -re -f rtp rtp://234.5.5.5:1234
```

You'll need to replace plughw:1,0 with your specific sound card. See arecord -l for info. On my Rasp Pi it went from ~95% CPU to ~35%.

Answer (score 7):

## ALSA Input

One alternative is to go via ALSA. A similar command to above would be

```
ffmpeg -ac 1 -f alsa -i hw:0,0 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ac 1 -re -f rtp rtp://localhost:1234
```

I'm not sure how this will affect the CPU usage.

Comment: I tried : ffmpeg -ac 1 -f alsa -i hw:1,0 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ac 1 -re -f rtp rtp://192.168.1.116:1234 But ffmpeg crashes after somes seconds : [alsa @ 0x7a1510] ALSA buffer xrun. Any other ideas ?

Comment: I tested ffmpeg -f oss -i /dev/dsp1 -ab 32k -ac 1 -re -f rtp rtp://192.168.28.116:1234 but the sound is very bad... on the lag is around 6 seconds. Any idea to have a better solution ?

Comment: @si2w I think 32k for mp3 is a bit of a joke. Either up that, or try a different codec. Maybe one of the G2xx series designed for telephones

Answer (score 4):

This works and reduces cpu usage:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i default:CARD=U0x46d0x819 -acodec mp2 -ac 1 -re -f rtp rtp://234.5.5.5:1234 2> /tmp/mylog.log &
```

Be sure to replace default:CARD=U0x46d0x819 with your microphone ID, ( obtained from arecord -l ) or you cad specify `-i hw:0,0` (or whichever device it is).

I had a similar problem -- mp3 encoding took up 90%+ of cpu power and just could not keep up with the audio -- so I changed it to mp2 encoding. This used about 15-18% of CPU (measured vi `top`) and streams smoothly to VLC on my LAN. It would make a perfect baby monitor, or whatever. There is just a second or so delay, which is the buffering at the VLC end.

**Note:** The ip address is a multicast address ([224-239].x.y.z). You don't have to aim it at a particular network device on your LAN, and your broadband router will keep the traffic local (by default).

Answer (score 2):

You can significantly reduce the CPU load by reducing the audio sample rate of the input device (`-ar 8000` **before** `-f alsa`), and setting the codec audio bit rate to 128k (`-b:a 128k`). Also ironically reducing the number of channels (`-ac 1`) seemed to increase the CPU load so I have found this command runs at pretty low CPU:

```
ffmpeg -ar 8000 -f alsa -i hw:0 -acodec mp2 -b:a 128k -f rtp rtp://other:4444
```

Although one needs to remember that it also depends on the capabilities of the capture hardware one is trying to use, and the versions of ffmpeg/avconv.